# HTML link to postgres database

Tags: html, postgresql

I want to create a link like

```
<a href="mailto:name@email.com">Link text</a>
```

But instead of mailing a specific person I want it to open a postgresql tool with as much settings that are available.

Understand that this will depend a lot on the client settings, but just want to give it an decent chance of working if there is such a thing.

Experimented unsuccessfully with

```
<a href="postgres:user:password@database">Connect</a>
```

Comment: I believe there is not such a thing like `postgres` for `href` what you can do is create function in JS which open postgress tool and call that method in that link `<a onclick="yourFunctionHere()" href="javascript:void(0);">` but also I believe it must be some kind of service running in NODEjs cause you will not have access to your pc from browser level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, HREF links are not restricted to HTTP-based URLs, but the list is quite short. They can use any URL scheme supported by browsers, the usual `http`, the `mailto`you mentionned or even `tel` for phone numbers. `postgres` is not an option, however with [registerProtocolHandler()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler) you can add your own.

That means that you can use [registerProtocolHandler()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler) to register `postgres`in order to open a specific link on your page. But that's not yet the solution to your question... You  need then to have this specific link to point to some postgres service

Comment: Nice, didn't manage to find the documentation. Thanks for the clarification